# Style not working when using Foundation Zurb in MVC in VS 2013

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

Hope you can help me with the following:

I already created an MVC site in Visual Studio 2013. It runs OK using Bootstrap as expected. NOW, that I want to use the Foundation framework in the site as well, I'm having some problems when trying to execute the site.

Here's what I already did:

1. I downloaded and installed the Foundation Zurb package using the Nuget package manager
2. I added some extra files to my project (the foundation folder with its corresponding .css files)
3. Then I opened the BundleConfig.cs file to bundle the new JS and CSS files.

   //Add the Foundation scripts
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/foundation").Include(
   "~/Scripts/foundation/foundation.*",
   "~/Scripts/foundation/jquery.cookie.js",
   "~/Scripts/foundation/fastclick.js"));

   //Add the Foundation styles
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/foundation").Include(
   "~/Content/foundation/foundation.css",
   "~/Content/foundation/foundation.mvc.css",
   "~/Content/foundation/normalize.css"));
4. I compiled the solution without any error
5. Then clicking on the Run button to execute the page in Firefox or Google Chrome
6. However the html code that used the styles are not working properly. This is the html code:

   [image: profile image] 
           
           
              John Doe President of XPTO

   smtsmt@smt.com

   @username

   thisisme@myemai.com

   Followers 432

   Following 432

   Views 432

Is there something that I' missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

3.5 Add new bundles to layout

```
//razor markup
@Styles.Render("~/Content/foundation")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foundation")
```

Comment: I have already do that at the begining without any luck. After I configured it in the BundleConfig.cs file I added that code. Also pointing out that when debugin it in Chrome it says that Foundation folder was not found. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It's silly, but in my case the problem was, that bundles registration in **Global.asax.cs** file was missing in Application_Start() method:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles( BundleTable.Bundles );
```

remember to add

```
using System.Web.Optimization;
```